# Why won't it sort alphabetically?

Tags: sorting

I am trying to sort something alphabetically in Adobe Air but it isn't working.

```
function alphabeticalSort(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var scores:Array = [boxContents1]; 
    scores.sort(Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);  
}
```

Comment: Is it crashing or is it producing unexpected results? Are you getting an error message? You'll have to give us more to work with than this.

Comment: It looks like you are copying the contents of a control to an array and then sorting the array. It seems to me like you still need to copy the contents of the array back to the control.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website so I wasn't sure exactly what to write. I have scores from a quiz which are being imported (as they are supposed to be) but the button which is supposed to sort them alphabetically just doesn't sort them. Other than that the program runs fine and no error messages show.